# Ajax request data passing between components

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am trying to get the reddit topic results from AJAX request and it seems my current approach of passing the posts results is wrong.

Currently I have created three web components, separate service for the ajax requests which passes the response via attribute. 
Separate search component which has text input field changes the category for the 'service'.
The search component pass the posts to listing service.

The problem is with the passing posts data from search component to list component.

reddit-post-service.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="reddit-post-service" attributes="posts subreddit">

  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: none;
    }
    </style>

    <core-ajax id="ajax"
      url="http://www.reddit.com/r/{{subreddit}}/new.json"
      on-core-response="{{postsLoaded}}"
      on-core-error="{{handleError}}"
      auto
      handleAs="json">
    </core-ajax>

  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer('reddit-post-service', {

    created: function() {
      console.log('Reddit post service created');

      this.posts = [];
    },

    postsLoaded: function() {
      // Make a copy of the loaded data
      this.posts = this.$.ajax.response.data.children
      .map(function (post) {
        return post.data;
      });
    },

    handleError: function () {
      this.posts = [];
    }
  });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

reddit-search.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="reddit-post-service.html">

<polymer-element name="reddit-search" attributes="posts">
  <template>
    <style>
      paper-button.search {
        background-color: #19D820;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-input label="subreddit name" tabindex="0" value="{{subreddit}}"></paper-input>
    <paper-button label="Search" tabindex="1" class="search"></paper-button>

    <reddit-post-service subreddit="{{subreddit}}" posts="{{posts}}"></reddit-post-service>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('reddit-search', {

      subreddit: 'programming',

      // initialize the element's model
      ready: function() {

      } 
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

post-list.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../post-service/post-service.html">
<link rel="import" href="post-card.html">

<polymer-element name="post-list" attributes="show posts">
  <template>
    <style>
    :host {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>

      <div layout vertical center>
        <template repeat="{{post in posts}}">
          <!-- Never reach this block -->
          <span>{{post}}</span>
        </template>
      </div>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer({
  });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>unquote</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <script src="../components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="../components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="../components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">


  <link rel="import" href="post-list.html">
  <link rel="import" href="reddit-search.html">
  <link rel="import" href="name-tag.html">
  <style>
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <core-header-panel>

    <core-toolbar>
      <paper-tabs valueattr="name" selected="new" self-end>
        <paper-tab name="new">NEW</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab name="favorites">FAVORITES</paper-tab>

      </paper-tabs>

      <reddit-search posts="{{posts}}"></reddit-search>
    </core-toolbar>

  <!-- <name-tag></name-tag> -->
    <!-- main page content will go here -->
  <div class="container" layout vertical center>
    <post-list show="all" posts="{{posts}}"></post-list>
  </div>

  </core-header-panel>

  <script>

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data-binding via '{{ }}' only works in the context of a template. Your `index.html` attempts to use binding outside of a template.

You can fix this by making your main application itself a `polymer-element`, by using some other system for propagating the data, or by using an `auto-binding` template, like this:

```
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <core-header-panel flex>
      <core-toolbar>
        <paper-tabs valueattr="name" selected="new" self-end>
          <paper-tab name="new">NEW</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="favorites">FAVORITES</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
        <reddit-search posts="{{posts}}"></reddit-search>
      </core-toolbar>
      <div class="container" layout vertical center>
        <post-list show="all" posts="{{posts}}"></post-list>
      </div>
    </core-header-panel>
  </template>
```

See http://jsbin.com/xahoc/2/edit

Comment: Thank you, it's working great. What to you think should the ajax component be more loosely coupled, as it's currently tight coupled with the search component ?